# Can You Go Over The 255 RGB Color Limit In Java

Tags: java

Would it be possible to use over 255 of red, green, and blue for colors in java? If so, how would those colors be used? I was wondering because I am making a program that produces rectangles with random colors, but most of the colors are similar. Is there any difference with using colors with values over 255 and colors with values under 255? Jpeg image formats use color values over 255 rgb, so would java be able to too? If I used a jpeg image, would the color still retain it's over 255 rgb color value?

This is my code for generating colors and drawing the shape to the screen:

```
    Random r = new Random();
    for(int i = 0;i<=shapes.size()-1;i++){
    Shape s = shapes.get(i);
    int red = r.nextInt(256);
    int green = r.nextInt(256);
    int blue = r.nextInt(256);
    this.colors.add(new Color(red, green, blue));
    //Draw the rectangle
    g.setPaint(this.colors.get(i));
    g.fill(s);
    //Draw the outline
    g.setPaint(Color.black);
    g.draw(s);
    }
```

I added the shape corresponding to the color in previous code.
"shapes" is my arraylist of shapes. "colors" is my arraylist of colors corresponding to each shape.

Comment: The upperbound is `255`, not `256`.

Comment: @CommuSoft: Since the individual Color fields are 0-based, that still translates to 256 steps for each sub-color, red, green, and blue. My question is why does the OP feel that he needs a resolution of more than 256 * 256 * 256 colors? This question is very unclear.

Comment: Well my impression was that the user wants to create a color like `(299,0,50)` thus with higher red intensity.

Comment: Until the original poster clarifies his problem, our guesses will likely be wrong.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: well when it comes down to resolution, there are indeed image formats and camera's that use a higher resolution than `256^3`.

Comment: @HelloWorld: please reformulate your question.

Comment: @CommuSoft: I don't disagree, but the question is very incomplete as written. It's like he didn't want to put much effort into it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: well I produced an answer before seeing your comment. From that point, I indeed saw that there are multiple interpretations. But because of the effort in the answer, I will keep it until proven it doesn't fit within the question.

Comment: @CommuSoft: well one plus for your effort.

Comment: `"but most of the colors are similar"` -- This has **nothing** to do with using 255 or 256 RGB values since 256 * 256 * 256 will offer plenty of resolution for creating varied colors, making your question a classic [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Consider showing your code and showing your colors for a better question and better answers.

Comment: @HelloWorld: I think the main problem is that you construct a random number generator within the loop.

Comment: How similar are "most of the colours"?

Comment: Every 7 colors a color repeats.

Comment: **Don't create a new Random object inside of your `paintComponent method**. Create a single Random object at the top of your class. Again, this has nothing to do with the so-called 256 resolution and all to do with problems with the code.

Comment: The Java Image API only supports up to 32bit Image format (RGBA x 8bit). There might be third party libs who can do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the encoding of color you use, but when it comes down to intensity no. `24`-bit means that each color is communicated by - as it says - sending `24` bits: a zero or one. `24` means `3` (the number of color channels) times `8`. Thus `8` bit or a `byte` per channel (red, green and blue). You can only represent `256` possibilities with `8` bit since it is `2^8=2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2=256`. So no. For `24`-bit colors. `255` is thus simply defined as the maximum intensity of red/green/blue a monitor renders. If you use default *Java* packages, I think they will (almost) always use `24` bit colors.

Now if you look into image formats, you will see some formats support higher bit rates. This only means that you define colors more precise. In other words if you would use a `48`-bit color representation, each color channel will have `16` bit. In that case `65 535` will be the maximum value, but that's (more or less) equivalent to the `255` for a `24`-bit color.

Most monitors only support `24`-bit colors. More bits are in general only used during rendering (to perform computations on an image). For instance if you implement a raytracer, you must add all kinds of origins of light together. Or if you implement a *Window environment* where different windows can have different transparency level, you could calculate intermediate results with higher precision to increase the quality of the result.

Some camera's capture color more precisely. This can be useful because industrial printers sometimes make their own ink and one can thus make colors more accurately. That's one of the reasons magazine pictures are typically better than the pictures one prints at home.

A final note is that some renderers or (computer graphics) camera's even use more color channels. A friend implemented a raytracer that rendered rainbows. In order to do that, he implemented a definition of color with seven color channels. You don't need them to display the image on the screen, but you need them to do the calculations on how light interacts with water.

**EDIT**

About your code:

The problem lies in your code:

The most important problem is probably that:

```
Random r = new Random();
```

is called **inside the loop**. This is a bit inefficient.

Next, it seems that you have **precoded** the list of colors. In that case, no random generator will alter the colors. Mind that `.add` simply **appends** your new `Color` to the **end of the list**.

Next you call:

```
g.setPaint(Color.black);
g.draw(s);
g.setPaint(this.colors.get(i));
g.fill(s);
```

So you first paint the shape in black and then repaint it in the color you've picked. Why? You can replace it by:

```
g.setPaint(this.colors.get(i));
g.fill(s);
g.setPaint(Color.black);
g.draw(s);
```

Finally you can make the construction of a color more efficient by calling:

```
Color c = new Color(r.nextInt(16777216));
```

So the resulting program will be something like:

```
Random r = new Random();
for(int i = 0;i<=shapes.size()-1;i++){
    Shape s = shapes.get(i);
    Color c = new Color(r.nextInt(16777216));
    g.setPaint(c);
    g.fill(s);
    g.setPaint(Color.black);
    g.draw(s);
}
```

Comment: The g.draw(s); part of it was to make an outline.

Comment: @HelloWorld: in that case, you better place it after filling. You must see it from the perspective of the [*Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm) a painter first paints the background and then add lines.

Comment: @HelloWorld: and as specified, I don't see why you add the `Color` to an arraylist if the you can use it directly.

Comment: I added the color because the color would change every time I ran the for loop.

Comment: Yeah sure, but do you do anything with it later in the process?

Comment: I save the image as a png file.

Comment: @HelloWorld: but you don't process the list of colors anymore. In that case it is useless to maintain them since the *Java garbage collector* will eventually remove them anyway.